# Strapi as general backend framework to build social app?

Tags: strapi, headless-cms, nuxt-strapi

I understand Strapi is a headless CMS. But I wonder if it can be used as a general backend framework (like Django) to build a social app.

By looking at its CRUD API capabilities, I feel it is possible; but on the other hand, the way Strapi boasts its [user management and RBAC](https://strapi.io/blog/announcing-3.1-role-based-access-control) makes me feel it is very much tailored for internally managed users

Can someone share your understanding and experience toward Strapi?

Comment: I was wandering the same thing. @chen did you come to any conclusion?